# Raspberry Pi won't start .jnlp file

Tags: raspbian, java-web-start, raspberry-pi3, icedtea

I've installed Java (1.8) and icedtea, but when I use `(sudo) javaws myapp.jnlp` it acts like it's going to start, prompting me with a "Are you sure you want to run this application" dialog, but when I click "Yes," it closes, stating this:

ERROR:  javax.jnlp.BasicService not available

This application must be started by Java Web Start

Is this a problem with icedtea or a problem with the application itself?  And, do you know how I can fix it?

I'm on a Raspberry Pi, but I don't know which one.  If I had to guess, I'd say it's a 3, and it's using Raspbian.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Icedtea Plugin by typing:

sudo apt-get install icedtea-8-plugin

If the File is still not opened look for it in the file manager.
Right click, open with... 
Second Tab "userdefined..."

/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-armhf/bin/javaws %f